# Aligning a Frame in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, frame

How to modify the height of the Frame layout. I have tried to set the HeightRequest for the frame, but it doesnt work. Please check the below and attached image.

**Frame**

```
Frame frame = new Frame()
            {
                HasShadow = false,
                Margin = new Thickness(10, 0, 0, 10),
                BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#CDD0D1")
            };
```

**Label**

```
 Label tag = new Label()
            {
                TextColor = Color.Black,
                FontSize = 14,
            };

            frame.Content = tag;
```

[image]

**Expected Output:** My excepted output should be rectangle frame instead of square.

Comment: What is the layout that your `Frame` is in?

Comment: @SuavePirate I have used StackLayout in the Frame.

Comment: The layout you're putting your Frame in is most likely restricting the Frame itself. Can you post the implementation for this? Width and Height requests do work, so it's most likely the context you're using the Frame in.

Comment: xamarin frame take 20 padding my default you can change it to 0

Answer (score 0):

Mainly,the frame control in Xamarin is take there own padding in all directions so  add padding 0 of frame as:

```
Frame frame=new Frame{Padding=new Thickness(0)};
```